# Aligning text on a specific character

Tags: html, css

I have this list of words i want to align on the center, every list item consists of two words divided by a '-'(hyphen). Is there an easy way i can align spot on the hyphen? When words are different in lenght now, the hyphen isn't in the center anymore.

I've made a fiddle to make my problem clear:
http://jsfiddle.net/seLvC/

my current code:

```css
.progress-ww {
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  line-height: 0.8rem;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="progress-ww">
    <div>
      <div>lopen - ik loop</div>
      <div>klimmen - ik klim</div>
      <div>geven - ik geef</div>
      <div>schreeuwen - ik schreeuw</div>
      <div>blozen - ik bloos</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: does the html have to remain the same?

Comment: It exists a syntax Character-based alignment in a table column : `text-align: "-" center;` seen on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-align

Comment: @Sandburg It exists, but browser support is… not great, to say the least: https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-css_properties_text-align_string

Answer (score 19, accepted):

One way of achiveing this is to place `spans` around the words on the left and right side of the hyphen.
Then you can add a min-width to these to make them equal width which will put the hyphen in the center.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/seLvC/9/)

```css
.progress-ww {
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  line-height:0.8rem;
  text-align:center;


}
.progress-ww span {
    display:inline-block;
    width:100px;
    text-align:left;
}
.progress-ww span:first-of-type {
    text-align:right
}
```

```html
<section>
    <div class="progress-ww">
        <div>
            <div><span>lopen</span> - <span>ik loop</span></div>
            <div><span>klimmen</span> - <span>ik klim</span></div>
            <div><span>geven</span> - <span>ik geef</span></div>
            <div><span>schreeuwen</span> - <span>ik schreeuw</span></div>
            <div><span>blozen</span> - <span>ik bloos</span></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

---

### **UPDATED VERSION USING FLEX**

Below is an updated version for this solution using flexbox. This solution means you don't have to set any fixed widths on the spans.

```css
.progress-ww div {
  display: flex;
}

.progress-ww div span {
  flex: 1;
}

.progress-ww div span:first-of-type {
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: 5px;
}

.progress-ww div span:last-of-type {
  padding-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="progress-ww">
    <div><span>lopen</span> - <span>ik loop</span></div>
    <div><span>klimmen</span> - <span>ik klim</span></div>
    <div><span>geven</span> - <span>ik geef</span></div>
    <div><span>schreeuwen</span> - <span>ik schreeuw</span></div>
    <div><span>blozen</span> - <span>ik bloos</span></div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: since it is the one solution  i like best :) +1 , cause , elements remains in the flow.

Answer (score 3):

## [Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/seLvC/7/)

If you want to use some jQuery (for example, if you cant change your HTML), another alternative may be:

```js
$('.progress-ww div').each(function() {
  var part = $(this).text().split(' - ')
  $(this).replaceWith("<div class='right'>" + part[0] + "</div><div class='left'>" + part[1] + "</div>");
});
```

```css
.progress-ww {
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  line-height: 0.8rem;
  text-align: center;
}

.left {
  text-align: left;
}

.right {
  text-align: right;
}

.right:after {
  content: ' -';
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.left,
.right {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="progress-ww">
  <div>lopen - ik loop</div>
  <div>klimmen - ik klim</div>
  <div>geven - ik geef</div>
  <div>schreeuwen - ik schreeuw</div>
  <div>blozen - ik bloos</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

im assuming you arent locked into using that html structure. as such i would not only use list items to display this series of items, but i would also wrap each section of them in `span` tags. **The perk to this solution is you are not locked into arbitrary widths for the left and right sections (you just have to worry about the width of the hyphen)**

js fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/seLvC/8/

HTML

```
<section>
    <div class="progress-ww">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <span>lopen</span>
                -
                <span>ik loop</span>
            </li>
            <li>
                <span>klimmen</span>
                -
                <span>ik klim</span>
            </li>
            <li>
                <span>geven</span>
                -
                <span>ik geef</span>
            </li>
            <li>
                <span>schreeuwen</span>
                -
                <span>ik schreeuw</span>
            </li>
            <li>
                <span>blozen</span>
                -
                <span>ik bloos</span>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</section>
```

CSS

```
*,
*:before,
*:after{
  -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
.progress-ww {
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  line-height:0.8rem;
  text-align:center;
}
ul{
    list-style-type:none;
}
    ul li{
        width:100%;
        position: relative;
    }
        ul li span{
            position: absolute;
            right:0;
            left:50%;
            text-align:left;
            padding-left:5px;
            display:inline-block;
        }
        ul li span:first-child{
            position: absolute;
            left:0;
            right:50%;
            text-align:right;
            padding-right:5px;
            display:inline-block;
        }
.hyphen{
    display:inline-block;
    width:10px;
}
```

EDIT: removed hyphen class and adjusted css order for IE8 compatibility - thanks to GCyrillus for the suggestion

Comment: no need of last-child nor to wrap hyphen in a box, just overwrite span rules with span:first-child in this peticular case , so no worries for IE8 :)

Comment: i suppose you could rely entirely on the padding-left/right on the first and last spans you're right.. i will amend my answer

Answer (score 1):

as I suggested in other answer , this could use the `<dl>` tags if semantics matters :

```
<div class="progress-ww">
  <dl>
    <dt>lopen</dt><dd>ik loop<br/>zij lopen</dd>
    <dt>klimmen</dt><dd>ik klim</dd>
    <dt>geven</dt><dd>ik geef</dd>
    <dt>schreeuwen</dt><dd>ik schreeuw</dd>
    <dt>blozen</dt><dd>ik bloos<br/>je bloos<br/>hij bloss</dd>
  </dil>
</div>
```

with css

```
.progress-ww {
  text-align:center;
  width:260px;
  /* margin : auto ; maybe ? */

}
dt , dd {
  width:100px;
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
  margin:0;
  padding:0 5px 0 0;
}
dt {text-align:right;}
dd {text-align:left;}
dt:after {content:' -';}
```

**[DEMO](http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/yvqzC/)**

Answer (score 0):

Not very clean.. but a solution nevertheless: http://jsfiddle.net/seLvC/5/.

CSS

```
.progress-ww {
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  line-height:0.8rem;
    text-align:center;
}

.hyp {
    position:relative;
}
.first, .second {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;    
}
.first {
    right:18%;     
    padding-right:35%;
}
.second {
    left:18%;     
    padding-left:35%;
}
```

sorry but I changed your HTML:

```
    <div class="hyp">
        -
        <div class="first">ik loop </div>
        <div class="second">lopen</div>
      </div>
      <div class="hyp">
        -
        <div class="first">klimmen </div>
        <div class="second">ik klim</div>
      </div>
      <div class="hyp">
        -
        <div class="first">geven  </div>
        <div class="second">ik geef</div>
      </div>
      <div class="hyp">
        -
        <div class="first">schreeuwen</div>
        <div class="second">ik schreeuw</div>
      </div>
      <div class="hyp">
        -
        <div class="first">blozen </div>
        <div class="second">ik bloos</div>
      </div>



      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no easy way to align to a specific character, and in fact no way with the given HTML markup.

The markup is best changed to a table, because that’s by far the most reliable way of achieving the desired appearance (even when CSS is off). It’s also the most logical approach, since the data is structurally a table of correspondences. Using `dl` would not be wrong if we adopt the HTML5 principle of `dl` as description list (not as definition list, as originally defined). But it offers no special benefits and causes some complications.

Example:

```
<table class="progress-ww">
    <tr> <td>lopen <td>- ik loop
    <tr> <td>klimmen <td>- ik klim
    <tr> <td>geven <td>- ik geef<
    <tr> <td>schreeuwen <td>- ik schreeuw>
    <tr> <td>blozen <td>- ik bloos
</table>
```

You can then easily style the table as desired. I’m not sure what kind of centering is desired, but you can center the table as a whole (e.g., in CSS with `table {margin: 0 auto}`), or you can right-align the first column (`td:first-child { text-align: right }`).

The markup would be even more logical without the hyphens in the content. You could omit them and generate them in CSS with the `:before` pseudo-element, if this suits you better.

(I would not use a hyphen “-” here; human languages don’t normally use hyphens that way. I would use an en dash “–” or maybe a colon “:”, which is often used to separate word forms in a paradigm.)

Answer (score -1):

you could wrap your text in an `inline-block` boxe and set a `width`, reset `text-align` and give a negative `margin` to reduce virtually it's size to zero :
http://jsfiddle.net/seLvC/2/

```
.progress-ww {
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  line-height:0.8rem;
  text-align:center;
}
.progress-ww span {
    display:inline-block;
    width:100px;/* give it a width */
    margin:0 -100px 0 0;/* 0 space needed on right side */
    text-align:left;
}
.progress-ww span:first-of-type {
    margin:0 0 0 -100px;/* 0 space needed on left side */
    text-align:right
}
```

[image: visual]

This would deserved to be tagged within `<dl>` `<dt>` `<dd>` list , as it's similar to a dictionnary. :)