# CSS Japanese text not centred in span

Tags: html, css

I have this Japanese text segmented into `<span>`s. In the images below I added red borders to the spans to illustrate the problem. The vertical text is achieved using the `writing-mode: vertical-rl;` CSS property on the surrounding div.

Browser: Chromium
[image: Japanese example text]

Browser: Firefox
[image]

Browser: Android
[image]

As you can see the text inside centred inside each span either having a gap left or at the top. Or in the case of Android it doesn't even seem to put each character inside of a square. Is there a way to ensure each character is perfectly centred inside of the `<span>`s?

Example HTML file:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ja">

<style>
    span {
        border: 1px solid red;
        text-align: center;
    }
</style>

<body>
    <div>
        <span>一</span><span>＋</span><span>三</span><span>＊</span><span>九十</span>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div style="writing-mode: vertical-rl">
        <span>一</span><span>＋</span><span>三</span><span>＊</span><span>九十</span>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

**Result seems to depend on the browser!**

Comment: add your code here

Comment: Text align? Without actual CSS code this is the best you're gonna get as an answer

Comment: Ok, added example code.

Answer (score 2):

It would be more helpful if I could see the CSS code, but try using the `text-align` CSS property if you haven't yet.
You can use it like this: `text-align: center;`

```css
span {
  border: 1px solid red;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ja">
<body>
  <div>
    <span>一</span><span>＋</span><span>三</span><span>＊</span><span>九十</span>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div style="writing-mode: vertical-rl">
    <span>一</span><span>＋</span><span>三</span><span>＊</span><span>九十</span>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to work. Also don't know what code to post, this seem to be default browser behaviour. Will add browser though.

Comment: Just show me the CSS code that you used to make the border around the letters.

Comment: When I edited my answer and looked at the code result, it looked centered. When I increased the `font-size`, it looked like the text was still centered. You can try running the code snippet.

Comment: Crap, I just tried it in Firefox and on my phone. It looks completely different depending on which browser I use it seems.

Comment: Is it better or worse?

Comment: Look at updated question for screenshots. (not better)

Answer (score 0):

You should look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22763127/aligning-text-on-a-specific-character/22763427) post. Try `padding-right` or `text-align: center` on the CSS. I could probably tell you what is is if I saw the code.

Comment: Look at updated question. Added super basic example html file. And text-align doesn't work (as added to example).